# Java remote JMX config gets ignored

Tags: java, jmx

I'm trying to create the correct remote JMX config for a Java process on:

- OpenJDK 8
- CentOS 7

The box seems to be provisioned correctly and the process being run ends up with the following vm options (confirmed using a `ps -ef` command):

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.config.file=/path/to/jmxremote.properties
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/path/to/jmxremote.access
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/path/to/jmxremote.password
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<<my_port>>
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<<my_port>>
```

The problem I'm facing is that after I start the process, no error is thrown, but the port is not open, whereas all the other ports opened by the application are.

Does anyone know why this config would be utterly ignored by the application?

Comment: `ps -ef` doesn't show envvars, and Java doesn't use envvars for this. The `-D` _commandline/exec argument/option_ is used to set _system properties_ -- but _only_ if it occurs _before_ the mainclass or jar, or module in 9+; do they?

Comment: Sorry, long night, I corrected the terminology. Yes, the system properties are specified before the classpath and the main class.